# How to terminate linux process from python by checking generated files for specific value?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, scheduling

I am running an executable (simulation) that generates each interval a new output-file. I want to check every output file for a certain value and when this value is exceeded, the simulation should stop. I am running this from a python script.

**This is what already works**

1. Run Executable from a python-script

*command = project_dir + '/EXECUTABLE/' + build_folder_name + '/INPUTFOLDER' + copied_file_path

os.system(command)*

2. As soon as Executable starts, a output-folder is created
3. Output-files are created one after the other (variable time-intervall)
4. evaluate each output file with evaluation_function and returns a value

**From here, I need help**

5. if the value doesn't change from one file to the next one, then terminate the process that runs the Executable
6. Else, the Executable will stop by itself because of some other termination criterion

I thought about using the subprocess but I am not quite sure how to use them. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this but with csv files.  If you use csv you can iterate through cells looking for data

using the csv module:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

we can set up a function to check for a condition

```
import csv
import sys
def condition(filename, condition):
     with open(filename + '.csv', 'r') as file:
          file_reader = csv.reader(file)
          for row in file_reader:
              if condition in row:
                 print('condition met')
                 sys.exit()
```

add this in and rewrite you output files as csv files instead I linked documentation in the answer so if you don't know how to use csv you can research it.

If you need to quit all python programs from terminal use

```
pkill python
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I cannot rewrite in csv. But suppose I can, it will terminate everything with sys.exit() no?

Comment: So it will also terminate the running python-script then? Because I will run it from the terminal

Comment: oh no if you want to kill python from terminal use the command I put under my code

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to put there your code if it's not a big project so we could find the best implementation for it.

Below you can see an example of how you can try to do it.

You can run the child processes as daemons in the background if it's not a big project.
Also you set up a queue for them so they could communicate with parent process.

Afterwards, using `.join` will help us with closing them.

Below is a code example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import queue

running_flag = mp.Value("i", 1)

def worker(running_flag, q):
    count = 1
    while True:
        if running_flag.value:
            print "working {0} ...".format(count)
            count += 1
            q.put(count)
            time.sleep(1)
            if count > 3:
                # Simulate hanging with sleep
                print "hanging..."
                time.sleep(1000)

def watchdog(q):
    """
    This check the queue for updates and send a signal to it
    when the child process isn't sending anything for too long
    """
    while True:
        try:
            msg = q.get(timeout=10.0)
        except queue.Empty as e:
            print "[WATCHDOG]: Maybe WORKER is slacking"
            q.put("KILL WORKER")

def main():
    """The main process"""
    q = mp.Queue()

    workr = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(running_flag, q))
    wdog = mp.Process(target=watchdog, args=(q,))

    # run the watchdog as daemon so it terminates with the main process
    wdog.daemon = True

    workr.start()
    print "[MAIN]: starting process P1"
    wdog.start()

    # Poll the queue
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        if msg == "KILL WATCHDOG":
            print "[MAIN]: Terminating slacking WORKER"
            workr.terminate()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if not workr.is_alive():
                print "[MAIN]: WORKER is a goner"
                workr.join(timeout=1.0)
                print "[MAIN]: Joined WORKER successfully!"
                q.close()
                break # watchdog process daemon gets terminated

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you very much. It seems that this is what i need but i somehow cannot undestand what happens in your code. Could you explain a bit what does what?